# Форма числа местоимения

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, местоимение

> Заседания избирательной комиссии, комиссии референдума созываются
> **ее** председателем по мере необходимости.

Как вы думаете, в какой форме числа должно быть представлено местоимение *ее*?
С одной стороны, *ее* правильно стоит в форме единственного числа, поскольку главные слова представлены в форме единственного числа. С другой стороны, все же главных слов несколько: избирательная **комиссия** и **комиссия** референдума. Это две различные комиссии с различными председателями.

Чем (каким правилом) можно руководствоваться при выборе формы числа местоимения в данном примере? Срабатывает ли в данном случае значение дистрибутивности при форме единственного числа слова *председатель*?

Comment: без "её", и сделать фокус на субъекте, а не на объекте. Например: Для проведения выборов или референдумов собираются комиссии. У каждой комиссии назначают председателя - лицо осуществляющее руководство комиссией. Сложные вопросы могут быть рассмотрены на заседаниях. Председатель организует созыв заседания комиссии по мере необходимости...

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но такой вариант выхода из ситуации нарушает требование юридической техники по лаконичному изложению. Такой правкой мы вляпаемся в многословие и бессодержательность. Поэтому интересует строго представленный пример. К слову, подобные случаи уже существуют в действующих нормативных актах, их уже не исправишь, остается лишь рассуждать, насколько это правильно.

Comment: тогда "созываются председателем(этой) комиссии". "Её" тут неуместное местоимение. Если это юр документ, то на повтор слова комиссия никто не будет внимание обращать, это лучше, чем ставить непонятные местоимения.

Comment: то есть юр понятия существуют через родовые определения, вроде "председатель комиссии", а не "её председатель", это не совсем русский литературный.

Comment: да, вы правы, лучше уж такой конструкцией. Правда, все же это не отменяет того, что такие примеры есть в действующих федеральных законах ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ как тогда квалифицировать эту ошибку? вроде, местоимение ничего не нарушает.

Comment: Юридические понятия, действительно, имеют строгие требования к применению в тексте нормативного акта. Но не в данном случае. Здесь конструкции "ее председатель" и "председатель этой комиссии" эквивалентны. Но, кстати, вторая проблему решает, можно апеллировать к значению дистрибутивности у единственного числа.